# Define Float32Array if undefined

Tags: javascript

What is the best way to fully define Float32Array JavaScript type, if (and only if) it is not defined?

Many android phones and windows tablets throw one of these errors:

- ReferenceError: Float32Array is not defined
- Can't find variable: Float32Array
- Float32Array is niet gedefinieerd

I want a solution without jQuery and without other plus codes, like these:

https://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/closure/goog/vec/float32array.js?r=9113191eff333b27475071053b5d119a3f0b881c

https://github.com/inexorabletash/polyfill/blob/master/typedarray.js

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/inexorabletash/polyfill

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while I was using JavaScript.net .

I have solved it like this

```
context.Run("var self = this; var global;");

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("typedarray.js")) //added typedarray.js (with path)
{
     context.Run(sr.ReadToEnd().ToString());
}
```

Comment: Please rate if you find my answer useful